# Расстановка запятых.

Tags: запятая

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как верно расставить запятые в предложении:"У бабушки в деревне я, нагулявшись по лесам и полям, пью чай, ем малиновое  варенье и после непродолжительных разговоров ложусь спать".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас правильно расставлены знаки препинания в приведенном предложении.

Answer (score 2):

Хорошо бы местоимение "я" переставить: "У бабушки в деревне, нагулявшись по лесам и полям,  я пью чай, ем малиновое варенье и после непродолжительных разговоров ложусь спать". Чувствуете, как меняется интонационная структура предложения, язык "не спотыкается" на этом слове? А с точки зрения грамматики, это два обстоятельства, отнесенные ко всему предложению. Их лучше поставить на первое место.

Comment: Спасибо! А мне почему-то все хочется поставить запятую перед "И". Или же выделить запятыми "после непродолжительных разговоров". Объясните, если не трудно, почему запятые здесь не нужны. Спасибо.

Comment: Перед И явно запятая не нужна, т.к. И -одиночный союз, соединяющий однородные сказуемые, а вот авторское выделение  "после непродолжительных разговоров " возможно, если Вы придаёте обороту смысл пояснения. Но это будет авторская пунктуация, факультативная.

Comment: Людмила, спасибо, что разъяснили. А то я, читая это предложение, непроизвольно выделяю паузами "после непродолжительных разговоров". Поэтому мне казалось, что недостает запятых. И все сомневалась - нужны они или нет?

Comment: Постановка "лишних" запятых связана с делением предложения на речевые отрезки (4-5 слов), которые мы произносим на одном дыхании, и именно речевые паузы становятся причиной необоснованной постановки запятых. В приведенном предложении 4 фразы, причем замыкающая фраза «и после непродолжительных разговоров ложусь спать" очень длинная, поэтому внутри этой фразы мы делаем «техническую» паузу. Обособление оборота  "после непродолжительных разговоров " приведет к его смысловому выделению и особой интонации второго плана, что в этом случае не кажется обоснованным.